# Exclude UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK and INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOG statements from SQL generated by Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

how do I exclude `UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` and `INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOG` from the SQL generated by executing `liquibase:update` command in Maven? I've tried the suggested solution of adding liquibase-nochangelogupdate to the POM, but how do I actually invoke it?

Thanks,
Angus

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If you prevent Liquibase of logging the executed changesets in `DATABASECHANGELOG` you completely break Liquibase. What's the point in that?

Comment: So that I can provide SQL scripts to DBAs that don't contain unnecessary commands.